# How do I display the company stock price changes in percentages and color?

Tags: javascript

I'm fetching data for a company profile and I would like to display the price change in percentage and red if negative or green if positive, to 2 decimal places.

```
// fetch for company profile
const companyTitle = document.getElementById("company-title");
const companyLogo = document.getElementById("company-logo");
const price = document.getElementById("price");
const companyDescription = document.getElementById("company-description");
const changesPercentage = document.getElementById("changesPercentage");

const symbol = window.location.search.replace("?symbol=", "");
// console.log(titleText);

if (symbol) {
  getCompanyProfile(symbol);
} else {
  alert("nothing is passed");
}

function getCompanyProfile(symbol) {
  const url = `https://appspot.com/api/v3/company/profile/${symbol}`;
  fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      const profile = data.profile;
      companyTitle.textContent = profile.companyName;
      companyDescription.textContent = profile.description;
      price.textContent = "Stock Price: $" + profile.price;
      changesPercentage.textContent = profile.changesPercentage;

      // set logo
      let img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = profile.image;
      companyLogo.appendChild(img);
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.warn("Something went wrong.", err.message);
    });
}
```

Comment: please includes your HTML and CSS files.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had to add an if statement to the function which first changed the the specific data point to a number and then looked at whether it is greater and equal to, or smaller than 0. In the former, it added a class of (green) and in the latter it added a class of (red). the toFixed(2) function condensed the number to two decimal points.

```
let profileChangesPercent = Number(profile.changesPercentage);

if (profileChangesPercent >= 0) {
    changesPercentage.classList.add("green");
} else if (profileChangesPercent < 0) {
    changesPercentage.classList.add("red");
}
changesPercentage.textContent = profileChangesPercent.toFixed(2) + "%";
```